# Selecting not previously selected questions in exsheets

Tags: exsheets, exercises, probsoln

Is it possibile, using `exsheets`, to randomly select not recently selected question (like `probsoln` does, for example)?

Comment: I think it's possible with  something like `\includequestions[random=??, exclude=\questionsincludedlast]{filename(s)}`. You may want to append the list provided by `\questionsincludedlast` from selection to selection and remove the old entries after `n` selections   depending on your understanding (preference) of the word "recently".

Comment: Thank you! Where is the `\questionsincludelast` list stored?

Comment: `\questionsincludelast` is a macro, initially empty  I presume, that returns a list of question IDs used at the previous `\includequestions` command -- see manual p.36. You'll have to use it to add the ID list it returns to your custom list, say `\recentlist`, which you create (empty) and then update (append the new IDs to it) after every new `\includequestions`.  In other words, you'll have to create the code to store the lists `\questionsincludelast` returned after every extraction. That's the theory I had in mind anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of effort this is surely possible. Two things are necessary:

1. update a clist of previously included questions
2. expand said list before passing it to the `exclude` option

The following code enables the first by appending the current value of `\questionsincludedlast` to the contents of the newly defined `\includedquestions`. The code assumes the package `etoolbox` loaded (which is loaded by `exsheets`:

```
\newcommand*\includedquestions{}
\newrobustcmd*\updateincludedlist{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\questionsincludedlast}
    {}
    {%
      \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\includedquestions}
        {\eappto\includedquestions{\questionsincludedlast}}
        {\eappto\includedquestions{,\questionsincludedlast}}%
    }%
}
```

The next code uses the above to pass the expanded list to the `exclude` option of `\includequestions`:

```
\newrobustcmd*\includequestionsX[1][]{%
  \updateincludedlist
  \edef\x{\includequestions[exclude={\includedquestions}}%
  \x,#1]%
}
```

An example of usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-questions.tex}
\begin{question}[ID=A]
  A
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=B]
  B
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=C]
  C
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=D]
  D
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=E]
  E
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=F]
  F
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=G]
  G
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=H]
  H
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=I]
  I
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=J]
  J
\end{question}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*\includedquestions{}
\newrobustcmd*\updateincludedlist{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\questionsincludedlast}
    {}
    {%
      \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\includedquestions}
        {\eappto\includedquestions{\questionsincludedlast}}
        {\eappto\includedquestions{,\questionsincludedlast}}%
    }%
}

\newrobustcmd*\includequestionsX[1][]{%
  \updateincludedlist
  \edef\x{\includequestions[exclude={\includedquestions}}%
  \x,#1]%
}

\begin{document}

\includequestionsX[random=2]{\jobname-questions.tex}

\includequestionsX[random=2]{\jobname-questions.tex}

\includequestionsX[random=2]{\jobname-questions.tex}

\includequestionsX[random=2]{\jobname-questions.tex}

\end{document}
```